# laravel queue not working from custom class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

Im use database for queue.
`php artisan queue:work` not runned.
If I add to queue from `App\Models\Mail`: `ProcessMail::dispatch(['test' => 'test');` auto_increment value changed, but row does not exists in database, no errors in logs and no exception. If I try `ProcessMail::dispatch(['test' => 'test');` in controller that's work fine: row creates to database.
This is code of ProcessMail:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Log;

class ProcessMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $mailData;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param [] $mailData
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
        Log::info('job constructor');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('job handle');
    }
}
```

Queue table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `queue` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `payload` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attempts` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `reserved_at` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_at` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you share your queue table structure

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök Hello. I shared my structure, but it default from `php artisan queue:table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. I call `ProcessMail::dispatch(['test' => 'test');` after `DB::beginTransaction();` and because I debug - I run `DB::rollback();` So created job removed from table. This is solely my fault. Perhaps someone will save time.